# MSSQL Running IN OUT count Record

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a report that counts how many people are signed into a section or signed out of a section each day.

```
select inout.name_id, nametable.name, inout.datetime, inout.status, inout.section
from inout
join nametable on inout.name_id = nametable.name_id
where inout.date between '1/1/2016' and '1/3/2016'
order by inout.date
```

Sample Data:

```
Datetime          Name   Section  Status
1/1/2016 1:34:56  John   A        IN
1/1/2016 4:11:11  Steve  A        OUT
1/1/2016 18:20:20 Bill   A        IN
1/2/2016 13:13:13 John   A        OUT
1/2/2016 12:12:12 Ben    A        IN
1/3/2016 1:01:01  JIM    A        IN
```

Then final result:

```
Date      # of people in section

1/1/2016          2
1/2/2016          2
1/3/2016          3
```

EDIT: Was thinking IN status would give +1 to a running count and OUT would give -1, so if a person came into work or left work for the day i could see how many people are working in a specific section each day, I'm not quite sure how to show for the people that were there before that date range either though.

Comment: I couldn't understand what is +1 and -1 can you explain more clearly?

Comment: I was thinking if the person had the IN status it would add +1 to the count, and if they had the out status it would -1. Like its counting how many people are in each section for those dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but may help others to visualize and may inspire you (but i think you did try it):

1. Use the query you have posted.
2. In Crystal designer, create a group by the column 'Datetime'.
3. Create a formula: `if {inout.status} = "IN" then 1 else -1`. Let's say it's name is @Quantifier.
4. Create a running total field: field to summarize = @Quantifier, type of summary = sum, evaluate for each record, reset never. Let's call it #NumberOfPeopleInSection_CloseButNoCigar.
5. Put the running total field in the group footer.

The result, as you said you expected, is not really what you want, because there is this "Steve out" without a previous "Steve in". So it still needs a trick.

[image]

To turn it in a solution, you may try another query to get the initial count. Try something to:

```
select sum(case when status='IN' then 1 else -1 end)
from inout
join nametable on inout.name_id = nametable.name_id
where inout.datetime < '2016-1-1'
```

Then consider this initial value in the final result.

Comment: The last column with label "INvsOUT" is the formula @Quantifier